# C++ arithmetic if operator

Tags: c++

I've been trying to get the arithmetic if operator to work but I just can't seem to do it.
I'm new to C++ and still learning the basics but I'm just wondering if I'm using this operator correctly. It's supposed to return false if x < y. Is this the correct way to do it? I'm aware I can use an if else but I'm just wondering if I can also do it like this and if I can what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int x =0;
int y =1;

bool test()
{
    return (x < y) ? true : false;
}

int main()
{
cout << test;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this is an example, but just so no one gets the wrong idea: in this case, you would just write `return x < y;` and be done with it.

Comment: No need for the ternary operator, "return x < y;" will work fine.

Comment: Also, just for interest, try "cout << std::boolalpha << test() << endl"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You state:

> It suppose to return **false** if x < y

And you're trying to learn about the arithmetic if (ternary) operator, so ignore all the advice to eliminate it.

The first part after the `?` is what will be returned if the expression is true, and the second part after the `:` is what will be returned if it is not true. Thus you have your return values reversed, and it should be:

```
return (x < y) ? false : true;
```

Answer (score 16):

Change

```
cout << test;
```

to

```
cout << test();
```

Otherwise you're not calling the function.

Also, the following:

```
return (x < y) ? true : false;
```

does the **opposite** of what you say you're trying to do ("return false if x < y").

The correct way is:

```
return (x < y) ? false : true;
```

Note that in this case the ternary operator is unnecessary, since you can simply do:

```
return !(x < y);
```

Comment: +1. Note that increasing the warning level on your compiler would have probably warned about a conversion from a function pointer to `void *` here.

Comment: -1 the OP said "return false if x < y" and this answer doesn't address that.

Answer (score 0):

Or even more simply,

```
return (x >= y);
```

Comment: always add a description so another user can better understand your solution and might find better than other answers.